# Cookie not remembered on IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies

I used a plugin for a popup that uses a cookie. [Link to plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/EU-Cookie-Notice-Plugin-jQuery-CookiePopup/)

It is working on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE and Edge. It is setting the cookie but when you close and re-open the broswer, it is gone and the popup shows again.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function saveCookie() {
    var expires = "expires=01/01/2099"
    document.cookie = "cookiesAccepted=true; " + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

I read something about "=" should be '=' but that didn't seem to help.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: I think the date format you have used in your `expires` setting is not valid, so the cookie will be using the default behaviour of expiring whenever the browser is closed. See the line about "expires" here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Write_a_new_cookie

Comment: Yes thank you for the tip. I changed it to var expires = "expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT"; Funny thing that in IE it only work the second time I open the browser.